# Eventbridge target to redshift to insert event data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-event-bridge

Steps followed to insert event data to redshift database

1. Have created redshift cluster with VPC. created database and schema
2. Created eventbridge rule with target redshift
3. SQL query used `insert into dev.schema (a,b) VALUES (event.data.a,event.data.b)`
   [image: Query used]

[image: Other config]

[image: Target config]

But if the event triggers for the particular name the data is not inserted in the redshift

Is there any specific SQL query methods available to push the event data to redshift database schema

Comment: Did you get any error information?  Any indication of where the process failed?  My one guess looking at what you have shown is that you didn't COMMIT the results of the insert statement.

Comment: Not sure where to check the error or failure so I tried with dead letter SQS queue if the event is not processed. I am receiving all the events as messages in the SQS. Can you please guide if you know how to change the query based on the event data. I think SQL statement where it's failing

Comment: So is you table called "schema" and it is located in schema "dev"?  Did you create a table?  What's its DDL (definition)?  INSERT needs the table to exist first.  If the table exists then the data types need to match the values you are inserting (INTs, I assume).  Lastly the results of the INSERT needed to be COMMITted (saved).  You can just add "; COMMIT ;" to you SQL to make sure this happens.

Comment: Yes the schema is exist in the database. Yeah will try with COMMIT;

Comment: Just want to make sure we are on the same page.  The table needs to exist as well.